# My Sql update gone wrong

Tags: mysql

Upgrade from version 4 to version 5 and now the databases are missing and I have no idea where to find them.  They are some *.frm files but how to fix it?

Comment: This is very light on details. Please include: what OS you are using (version, architecture), the procedure you followed to perform the upgrade, what you mean when you say the databases are missing.

Answer (score 0):

/var/lib/mysql

is the most standard place..

What operating system? Binaries or Precompiled

Answer (score 0):

Do you have backups?  Upgrading without backups is a VERY bad idea.  If you have backups I would go ahead and load them...